# Clarity on what actually happens at compiler level in memory management in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

1. In ARC when is the strong object actually released from memory. As in ARC we won’t  we using any release and dealloc to decrement its reference count. Is there any event cycle?
2. Also same with the weak, how long it remains in memory and at what time system releases it.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the object is weak or strong, it's the same: The object is deallocated when there are no more strong references to it. (Obviously, that means that you don't use weak reference unless there's something else with a strong reference to that object.)